# About html Decode and Encode type ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-encode

I have a snippet `<h2>SomeText</h2>`

When I saved in database from ckeditor change to it: **&lt;h2&gt;SomeText&lt;/h2&gt;**

now when I am using @WebUtility.HtmlDecode alone it's not display correctly and change to it: **&amp;lt;h2&amp;gt;SomeText&amp;lt;/h2&amp;gt;**

So When I am using @Html.Raw alone it's not display correctly and chage to it: `&lt;h2&gt;SomeText&lt;/h2&gt;`

**Now:**

I can't understand why did not work alone when I am using @Html.Raw or @WebUtility.HtmlDecode?
but when I am using First @WebUtility.HtmlDecode and next @Html.Raw together it's work correctly like it.  `@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@Item.Content))`

> **&lt;h2&gt;SomeText&lt;/h2&gt;** Stored in @Item.Content

Comment: do you use submit button to save ckeditor value?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
@Html.Raw("&lt;h2&gt;SomeText&lt;/h2&gt;")
```

this will decode the encoded data to html and will store it in DB
u r trying to decode and thn u r again encoding it 
thats the reason u getting the html encode data in DB

Comment: I was written in question. when I am using HtmlDecode (webutility or httputility also @html.raw) alone it's not display correctly.

Comment: you say Raw avoid Html Encoding but in this video using "Raw" and display correctly.

Comment: ya, html raw avoid encoded code and it will convert tht code in to normal html tags and values
Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt;h2&gt;SomeText&lt;/h2&gt;"))
Return Some Text in Bold Format 
#tried

Comment: I don't understand difference of "&lt;h2&gt;SomeText&lt;/h2&gt;" and "&amp;lt;h2&amp;gt;SomeText&amp;lt;/h2&amp;gt;"

Comment: &lt;h2&gt;SomeText&lt;/h2&gt is a html.encoded value
And &amp;lt;h2&amp;gt;SomeText&amp;lt;/h2&amp;gt; is browser encoded value , this is how browser reads the data

Comment: when I am using HtmlDecode inner Html.Raw it's done but when used Htmldecode and get result in view source and use this for Html.Raw it's display incorrect!!!

Comment: thats because , 
html.raw() -  as i told u will avoid the html encoded code , the best use of html.raw is to avoid server side scripting attack, so this html.raw will avoid the html code and tags and it will return the simple text, where as htmldecode in htmlraw() will read the html  encoded encoded and decode it as specified

Answer (score 1):

if you are using submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="save html" onclick="saveIt()" />
```

do like this:

```
function saveIt(){
     $('.editor').val(encodeURIComponent($('.editor').val()));
}
```

or If you just saving its value by ajax you then you can post `encodeURIComponent` of the html instead of html itself.

now `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` should work perfectly.

Comment: The question was written incorrectly. Questions were modified

Comment: Dear Ashkan I was saved html by ckeditor in webform version normallty and display with mvc version

Comment: I don't encoding html. I think ckeditor encoding html when send to code behind